# NSRegularExpression to remove white space

Tags: iphone, ios4, removing-whitespace

I need a little kickstart on regex on the iPhone. Actually I am dealing with UITextField.text. If the value of the text is empty and if the value already exist, I can able to deal it. But, if the value is simply white spaces, I do not want to use it. So, if the value is like "    " or "   folder", I want the value to be "" and "folder" respectively.

I planned to use NSRegularExpression to remove the white space and went through the documents. But it was little confusing. So, help me to come out of the problem of removing white space from the given string. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: you need to trim string, so no regular expression is needed, simply use:

```
[str stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
```

Comment: Thank you. But if my string is @"      jwhb kwbk   kweb", it gives the value, "      jwhb kwbk   kweb". But what I require is "jwhb kwbk   kweb". So, what would be the pattern?

Comment: I just wanted to remove the white space at the beginning of the string.

Comment: This answer does not answer the original question.

Answer (score 0):

The regexp would be:

```
/\s+/g
```

You would then replace that with ""

How you do that through iOS syntax for the replacement I don't know, but that's the regExp for it all :)

Answer (score 0):

A more practical question is, How to trim and condense white-spaces,

```
let text: String? = "  I    don't  know  you !  " // expected result: "I don't know you!"
let charSet = NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet()
if let trimmedText = text?.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(charSet).filter({!$0.isEmpty}).joinWithSeparator(" ") {
    print(trimmedText) // I don't know you!
}
```